# Why is my NiFi PublishKafka processor only working with previous versions?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, producer

I am using Kafka 2, and for some reason the only NiFi processors that will correctly publish my messages to Kafka are PublishKafka (0_9) and PublishKafka_0_10.  The later versions don't push my messages through, which is odd because again, I'm running Kafka 2.1.1.

For more information, when I try to run my FlowFile through the later PublishKafka processors, I get a timeout exception that repeats voluminously.

```
    2019-03-11 16:05:34,200 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] o.a.n.p.kafka.pubsub.PublishKafka_2_0 PublishKafka_2_0[id=6d7f1896-0169- 
    1000-ca27-cf7f86f22694] PublishKafka_2_0[id=6d7f1896-0169-1000-ca27- 
    cf7f86f22694] failed to process session due to 
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while 
    initializing transactional state in 5000ms.; Processor Administratively 
    Yielded for 1 sec: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: 
    Timeout expired while initializing transactional state in 5000ms.
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while 
    initializing transactional state in 5000ms.
    2019-03-11 16:05:34,201 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] 
    o.a.n.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask Administratively Yielding 
    PublishKafka_2_0[id=6d7f1896-0169-1000-ca27-cf7f86f22694] due to uncaught 
    Exception: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout 
    expired while initializing transactional state in 5000ms.
```

My processor settings are the following:
[image]

All other configurations are defaults.
Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: In general the processor version should match the broker version, so I would expect PublishKafka_2_0 to work with your 2.1.1 broker. if it is not then you'll probably have to show the configuration of your kafka processor, as well as the errors and stacktraces from nifi-app.log

Comment: @BryanBende I put those in the original post now.  I've tried using this processor without transactions as well, but the result is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, one more question, in $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties what do you have for "listeners" ?  is it "listeners=PLAINTEXT=app03.dev.onyxgs.com:9092" ?

Comment: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092.  We've also tried app03.dev.onyxgs.com:9092 with the same result either way.

Comment: Hmm do you also have KAFKA_LISTENERS? I think there are two different properties, also KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS should use the hostname you want clients to connect to so I don't think localhost would work there

Comment: Ok so now I changed the listeners property to localhost seen above, and the advertised listeners to the regular external name - still no luck.  Everything starts up, but Nifi still tries and fails to connect to the Kafka broker 1 and cannot find it.  I'm setting up an unsecured Nifi container just to see if it's a network problem, but other than that, I got nothing.

Comment: Do you have a solution yet?